# Vba Dictionary not finding key

Tags: vba, dictionary

I'm not able to retrieve values from my dictionary, despite providing what looks to me like the correct key.

In my immediate window, I'm getting the following results:

```
?d.Keys(0)
Key

?range("A1").Value 'This contains the key
Key

‘Just to make sure there’s no weirdness going on with white space or anything else…
?d.Keys(0) = range("A1").Value
True 'So, these two values are the same right???
 

?d(d.Keys(0))
Value


?d(range("A1").Value)
'this returns blank
```

Any ideas what's driving this behavior?  If my cell value is equal to the key, why can't I use it to extract the value from the dictionary?

Edit: I should add, the key is quite long,  230 chars. Maybe that matters?

Comment: Is the key text or a numeric value ?  Did you maybe switch sheets while you were debugging and it's picking up a different sheet in the last test?

Comment: Can you put this in to a subroutine with example data which exhibits this problem so that it is possible for us to see scope of variables and their assignments?

Comment: Key is text. Because of privacy concerns at my employer,  I didn't post actual code, but in my tests I fully qualified my sheet reference.

Comment: @David I can't even reproduce it... :P it works as expected in my test sub.  I'll go back and compare them again...

Comment: I'm not sure length is as issue, sometimes there are errors at 255 or longer strings but I'm not sure that affects dictionary. are you sure Case is identical?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dumb mistake on my part.  I set the key to be the range itself, rather than setting the key to be the range's value.